# Cartesian Power of a list in Erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I'm trying to code an erlang Mastermind solver as an exercise (I'm a complete newbie, but I reckon it's an interesting exercise for a functional language)

I want it to be as general as possible, so I feel that I need a Cartesian Power function. Something like:

```
cart_pow([a,b],2) -> [[a,a],[a,b],[b,a],[b,b]]
cart_pow([a,b],3) -> [[a,a,a],[a,a,b],[a,b,a],[a,b,b],[b,a,a],[b,a,b],[b,b,a],[b,b,b]]
```

I can't think of a purely functional (recursive, map, fold...) solution.
Any clues? Bonus if it's lazy.

Answer (score 3):

Solution provided by @Ed'ka is laconic and nice, but despite this, its complexity is `O(N)`.

I'd suggest you to take into account [Exponentiation by squaring method](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), which provides `O(log(N))` complexity in calculations of power. Using this technique, cartesian power may be implemented in such way:

```erlang
%% Entry point
cart(List, N) ->
        Tmp = [[X] || X <- List],
        cart(Tmp, Tmp, N).

cart(_InitialList, CurrList, 1) ->
        CurrList;
cart(_InitialList, CurrList, N) when N rem 2 == 0 ->
        Tmp = mul(CurrList, CurrList),
        cart(Tmp, Tmp, N div 2);
cart(InitialList, CurrList, N) ->
        Tmp = cart(InitialList, CurrList, N - 1),
        mul(InitialList, Tmp).

mul(L1, L2) ->
        [X++Y || X <- L1, Y <- L2].
```

P.S. Example of usage from shell (I've packed function `cart` into mudule `my_module`):

```
1> c(my_module).
{ok,my_module}
2> 
2> my_module:cart([0,1], 2).
[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
3> 
3> my_module:cart([0,1], 3).
[[0,0,0],
 [0,0,1],
 [0,1,0],
 [0,1,1],
 [1,0,0],
 [1,0,1],
 [1,1,0],
 [1,1,1]]
```

Comment: mul was the piece that was missing. I couldn't get it to return the correct structure, mostly because I I didn't understand that the proper input wasn't ([a,b],[a,b]) but ([[a],[b]],[[a],[b]])

Comment: In function `mul` calculated cartesian product of two lists. You may notice that lists concatenation syntax used there (operator `++`). So, it means - that function works only with lists of lists. That's why you have to call `mul([[a],[b]], [[a],[b]])` instead of `mul([a,b], [a,b])`. If you look at entry point (function `cart/2`) - you may notice, that I **transform input list to list of lists** (by wrapping each element in its own list: `[[X] || X <- List]`, so list `[a,b]` transforms to `[[a],[b]]`).

Comment: It would be O(log(N)) if `++` operator was O(1) but unfortunately it is O(N) (where N is the length of the left argument) so effectively you are just replacing multiple `[|]` with a single `++`. Your solution does run faster (a constant difference) than the first version of mine, but I suspect it is due to the tail call in the second case. For example if I make my solution tail-recursive (see my update) it becomes quicker than yours (again, a constant difference).

Answer (score 2):

From Haskell implementation:

```
cart_pow(Xs, N) -> 
    sequence(lists:duplicate(N, Xs)).

sequence([]) ->
    [[]];
sequence([Xs|Xss]) ->
    [[X|Xs1] || X <- Xs, Xs1 <- sequence(Xss)].
```

Not sure how you can make Erlang's lists lazy though.

**Update:**
This version can be improved in terms of performance by simply making it tail-recursive (even though I believe there is no asymptotic differences between all three)

```
cart_pow(Xs, N) -> 
    sequence(lists:duplicate(N, Xs)).

sequence(Xss) ->
    sequence(Xss, [[]]).

sequence([], Acc) ->
    Acc;
sequence([Xs|Xss], Acc) ->
    sequence(Xss, [[X|Xs1] || X <- Xs, Xs1 <- Acc]).
```

In comparison with @stemm's version:

```
1> timer:tc(fun() -> length(tmp1:cart([0,1], 20)) end).
{383939,1048576}
2> timer:tc(fun() -> length(tmp1:cart_pow([0,1], 20)) end).
{163932,1048576}
```

**PS:** Or even better:

```
sequence(Xss) ->
    lists:foldl(fun(Xs, A) -> [[X|Xs1] || X <- Xs, Xs1 <- A] end, [[]], Xss).
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find this Stack Overflow question helpful, which deals with generating the Cartesian power of a list in functional languages. The question is targeted for F#, but there is a Haskell example in the comments as well: [F#: how to find Cartesian power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648532/f-how-to-find-cartesian-power)